# Group by time with postgres and jooq

Tags: java, sql, jooq

How to group by minute, hour, day, or week in jooq. I have found out that in postgres
we can use `date_trunc('minute', created_at)` function for that.

The simplified SQL I am using for that is:

```sql
select date_trunc('day', created_at) as date,
       sum(time_spent) as time_spent,
from progress 
group by date
```

How can I achieve the equivalent with jooq?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As always, if you're missing support for some vendor-specific functionality, you can easily build it yourself using [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/)

```java
public static <T> Field<T> dateTrunc(String datePart, Field<T> field) {
    return DSL.field("date_trunc({0}, {1})", 
        field.getDataType(), DSL.inline(datePart), field);
}
```

Comment: Aren't `DSL.minute` and `date_trunc` to minutes different things? The former providing ONLY the minutes themself and the latter returning a timestamp with some values set to 0? Isn't `DSL.trunc(Date, DatePart)` the exact equivalent of `date_trunc`? The docs read to me like this is what I'm looking for when I'm using `date_trunc('month', now())` currently.